# Migrating FBA from SP2010 to 2013

Tags: 2013, forms-authentication

I have a backup of my SP2010 FBA database from SQL2008, and I want to copy the data into SP2013. I know that I can restore the database into SQL 2012, but I also know that all the user records will have the ApplicationID from my SP2010 web app, and it won't match the ApplicationID of the new SP2013 web app.

I tried to edit the ApplicationID for one record, but I cannot as this field is related to others.

Another concern I have is that we use discussion boards extensively, so keeping content author ID matching user IDs when data migrated to SP2013 is critical.

So, my questions:

- Am I missing anything simple that will allow me to use the existing data in SP2013?
- Is there a way I can change the ApplicationID across all tables within the FBA database?
- Does anyone have any steps for migrating FBA stuff between 2010 and 2013?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things.

There is no need to change the applicationID.  You can use the exact same FBA database that you were using for SharePoint 2010. The applicationID used is based on the ApplicationName in your membership provider settings in your web.config.

As long as you use the exact same membership provider settings, including the name of the membership provider, the users should be automatically recognized and you shouldn't need any additional migration steps to remap them.  The user key that SharePoint uses to map to the users in your FBA database is a combination of the membership provider name and the username, which is why the membership provider name should be kept the same.

Comment: Fantastic! When I get back to my desk on Tuesday, I'll try this out and report back. Thanks Chris.

Comment: There seems to be something else I need to do. I have restored my database (using replace), and I can see all the data as expected. In IIS I can change the default providers for roles and members and see all the data there too, but when I try to login, I just get "The server could not log you in". I copied the membership provider from my 2010 web.config to my 2013 one (both application and STS). My passwords are 'Encrypted' - I'm wondering if my machinekey validationKey & decryptionKey need to be the same as well? Any ideas?

Comment: It was indeed the machineKey - it needed to be added to the STS web.config (not sure why it wasn't there in the first place), but once it was and updated to match my 2010 instance, it works. Thanks for keeping me from diving too deep for this, Chris.

Comment: Just a comment on using the password format of 'Encrypted' - I generally recommend people use a password format of 'hashed'. The reason being that: encrypted passwords can be decrypted, while hashed passwords cannot (making them more secure).  Also, for encrypted passwords, the same key is needed everywhere they are used, making it more troublesome to setup.

Comment: Agreed - if anyone reading this doesn't need to use Encrypted, select Hashed as your password format.