# SharePoint 2013 Migration to SharePoint 2016 with FBA

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, migration, forms-authentication

We are using SharePoint 2013 application (FBA Authentication Enabled).Now we want to migrate this application to SharePoint 2016. Here what my concern is:

- Is anything need to be done with FBA Database?
- When should I configure FBA. After Site migration or before?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reuse the SharePoint 2013 FBA database in SharePoint 2016 or you can create /setup FBA in SharePoint 2016 from scratch.

I would prefer to setup the FBA 1st then migrates the Site collections.

- Setup FBA in SharePoint 2016 using existing DB or brand new.

  - if using the 2013 FBA database, backup the DB and restore in 2016 environment, complete the SharePoint 2016 configuration (web.config changes, permission, STS configuration etc). [here is good article for Sharepoint 2016 FBA](https://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2016-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/)
- Now Test the web application with FBA
- Migrate the sites from 2013 to 2016 and test it

[another good article for troubleshooting](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/69125/migrating-fba-from-sp2010-to-2013)

Comment: Is that the same way if I use FBA Pack?

Comment: yes, it will be same.

Comment: The above link is not working. Please find the latest link for SharePoint FBA including SharePoint 2019 and SharePoint Subscription Edition https://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2016-sharepoint-2019-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/